# How to create a DFA for min. one 0 and max. three 1’s

Tags: dfa

For the following language I need to create a DFA, but automatons I create are always [nondeterministic finite ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z6k6.png) (I don’t know if it’s correct).

Σ = {0, 1}
L = {ω ϵ Σ* | (|ω|<sub>0</sub> ≥ 1) ∧ (|ω|<sub>1</sub> ≤ 3)}

Comment: If you accidentally (?) create an NFA, you can then just convert it to a DFA using subset-construction. What does your NFA look like?

Comment: @harold: I added a link to my automaton.

Comment: OK then just [turn it into a DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) and you're done

Comment: Any luck yet? I got [this](http://i.imgur.com/Ue4Pj9D.png)

Comment: Hi @harold, I got [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eKcC4.png). The transitions from `{q0, q4}` to `{q1}` and so on are missing in my DFA. But before looking at your DFA, I got the same idea as you that I have to add additional transitions over 1. But I don’t know if I can derive them from the NFA? E. g. the transition over 1 from `q0` to `q1` in the NFA is the transition from `{q0}` to `{q1}` over 1, but not `{q0, q4}` to `{q1}`? (Sorry for my English)

Comment: It's a DFA over the alphabet {0,1} so it needs for each state a transition with a 0 and a transition with a 1 (otherwise it's possible to "get stuck", which is not allowed in a DFA, so actually I missed two transition on the "empty state" but you know what they have to be). Anyway from `{q0, q4}` with a 1 step you can go from `q0` to `q1` in the NFA, and from `q4` nowhere so from `{q0, q4}` with a 1 step you can go to `{q1}`. From `{q3, q4}` you can't go anywhere with a 1 step in the NFA, so in the DFA it has to go to an "empty set" state (which has transitions to itself)

Comment: OK, I understand it, that was easier than I thought. Thank you very much! :-)
The "empty state" is the error state in this case?

Comment: @harold: Which tool did you use to draw the automaton?

Comment: Yes the "empty state" is where you go in the DFA if in the NFA you'd get stuck (and end up "not in any state"). I used LaTeX (with `\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}`) to draw it

Comment: YannickIhmels @harold you can also use [DOT (graph description language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language))  it is quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to convert the NFA to a DFA via [subset-construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) as suggested by [harold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555045/harold).

Answer (score 0):

try this DFA......
may be helpful for your need...[image]